# Proper library for enums

Tags: refactoring, object-oriented-design, project-structure

I'm trying to refactor some code such that the display is separate from the implementation, and I'm not sure where to put the existing `enum`s.

My project is currently structured as follows:

- **Utilities**
- **RemoteData** (*Depends on:* `Utilities`)
- **LocalData** (*Depends on:* `RemoteData`, `Utilities`)
- **RemoteWeb** (*Depends on:* `RemoteData`, `Utilities`)
- **LocalWeb** (*Depends on:* `RemoteData`, `LocalData`, `Utilities`)

I'm now trying to add "**ViewLibrary** (*Depends on:* `Utilities`)" to this list, and then adding it as a new dependency to both `RemoteWeb` and `LocalWeb`.  It will contain a set of interfaces which the other two projects will implement, use to populate the view, and then consume the result.

There's an `enum` which is currently used in all the projects *except* `Utilities`.  It thus lives in the `RemoteData` project, because everything else depends on it.  But this new `ViewLibrary` won't depend on either data project.  So how will it know about this `enum`?

Some options I see:

- Create a new project just for shared enum values.
- Add it to `Utilities`, even though it is related to data.
- Define it a second time in `ViewLibrary`, and require both `RemoteWeb` and `LocalWeb` to convert the one type into the other when they access the shared views.
- Add a dependency on `RemoteData` to the `ViewLibrary`, even though it's supposed to be independent of data-source.

Are there any better options?  Is this structure flawed to begin with?

Comment: `Utilities` should really be called `Common` or something similar, but that's where the enum belongs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Even though it's related to the data, and everything else in `Utilties` (so far) is entirely project independent?  I guess by renaming it to `Common` it would seem less odd...

Comment: Then make another library that is common to `Data` and put it there.  You already know the answer to this; do what makes sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yeah, you're right.  Still, good to get validation for it.  Want to make that an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you want to put code in libraries that are common to the other libraries in which they will be used, and name them accordingly.  So in your case, since the enum is common only to the RemoteData and LocalData libraries, and specific to this particular project, I would make a new library called `[ProjectName]Data` and put it there.

Comment: Might end up being a small library, but it is what it is.  Thanks.